# Reading the registry on a 64-bit machine

Tags: 64-bit, registry

I have developed a 32-bit application (build for x86) which will later be deployed on a 64-bit machine. I have set some configuration in registry so when the application starts on a 32-bit machine there is no problem reading its value, but when deployed on a 64-bit machine I can not read the value properly as the path of the registry is changed. To make things clear,
on a 32-bit machine I have the registry entry as follows.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApplication\InstallationPath]
```

"folder"="C:\Program Files\MyApplication"

But when I look on a 64-bit machine, this is shifted to:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\**Wow6432Node**\MyApplication\InstallationPath]
```

"folder"="C:\Program Files\MyApplication"

Inside my application I have to query the value of the installation path. The obvious thing I have done is query the value with the hardcoded string "HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyApplication\InstallationPath", but which is not valid for a 64-bit machine.

How do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your problem: the `Wow6432Node` is [transparent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724072%28VS.85%29.aspx) from the caller's point of view.

That means the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApplication\InstallationPath` will be automatically mapped to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyApplication\InstallationPath` when accessed from a 32-bit application running on a 64-bit machine.

So your code should work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the REGSAM samDesired argument of [RegOpenKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897%28VS.85%29.aspx) and many of the other registry APIs.

The important one for you is [KEY_WOW64_64KEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724878%28v=VS.85%29.aspx): *"Indicates that an application on 64-bit Windows should operate on the 64-bit registry view. For more information, see [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)."*

You can use that in a 32-bit app to force it to inspect registry keys in the "native" 64-bit areas on a 64-bit system. (You might want to check that you're running on 64-bit Windows and only pass the flag then; I'm not sure what it would do on a 32-bit machine. Pass zero for samDesired when you want the default handling.)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do anything special in your code. 32-bit applications transparently access the portion of the registry under `Wow6432Node`.

To convince yourself of this, launch the 32-bit build of regedit.exe (available under `Windows\SysWOW64`) and take look around the registry.